# Why cant I save a user with picture on Azure, while it works locally?

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller

I have a create method which works fine in localhost. It looks like this:

```
public PatientViewModel Create(PatientViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        model.patient!.photoPath = (model.file != null) ? UploadFile(model.file) : "placeholder.png";
        model.patient.appUser = appuserAwhole(model);
        model.patient.appUser.user = (!model.mode) ? model.user : model.Users!.Where(r => r.userId == model.userid).First();
        _idb.patients.Add(model.patient);
        idbSaveChanges();
        Patientfile pf = new Patientfile();
        pf.patientMail = model.patient.emailAddress;
        _fdb.patientfiles.Add(pf);
        fdbSaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return model;
}
```

This is my UploadFile method:

```
private string UploadFile(IFormFile photo)
{
    string wwwPath = this._env.WebRootPath;
    string contentPath = this._env.ContentRootPath;

    string path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "img\\PatientPhotos");
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    if (photo == null)
    {
        return "default.png";
    }
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
    {
        photo.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

I first get the wwwroot path and use this to save my image. If the image already exist, it uses the image thats already saved (i know this isnt ideal, but it works for me for now).

When I upload a file in localhost and submit, the patient gets saved and so does the image (in wwwroot). On Azure however, the patient and the image dont get saved.

When I dont upload a file, it automatically uses placeholder.png. Now the patient does get saved on Azure, but no image, since none was selected.

Im not getting any errors (probably because its in a production environment), it just returns to the Index page after submitting, without saving anything

In my controller you return to the Index page after creating the patient:

```
_db.Create(vm);
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: The folder either doesn't exist or you do not have the permission to write to the file.  Most servers like IIS users do not have permission to write to system resources like the file system. Writing to a network drive that allows writes may solve issue.  Or the default folder when you connect is wrong and you need to use the full path or use change folder before uploading.

Comment: When you say ‘on Azure’ do you mean running as an app service?

Comment: The folder does exist, and if it didnt, it should create the folder. Is there any way to give permission to write to the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Yes, its running as an App Service